# Winforms application - could not load file or assembly "Entity Framework"

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, desktop-application

I created for a client a small Winforms application using SQL Server 2012 for the database and Entity Framework to run the stored procedures inside my application.

When I run the application on the development machine, everything runs smoothly (as usual), then I created an installation package to transfer it to the client machine, and successfully installed it. I also installed SQL Server 2012 for the client and the application starts up and it can connect to the database (I know because the forms are reading data from the database). Now the problem is when I try to insert new data into the database through my application - I get this error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

I checked the config file and it stats the same version and key.

The results I got when I searched the issue is to update the Entity Framework from Nuget packages, but I am working on the client PC, should I try and deploy it again, or what should be my next step to solve this problem

Comment: Looks like a deployment problem. Have you tried to install the app on your development PC? Is the EF dll definitely in your deployment package and marked for deployment to the local bin folder

Comment: Also, see the first answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471347/entity-framework-5-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-entityframework-version-5) question on Fusion Logging

Comment: I installed it on the development pc and its running with no problems, I used installsheild limited edition to create my setup file and I dont this their was anything regarding the attachment of EF dll it only asked for required software, the EF dll fill is present in the folder of deployed app on the client machine

Comment: I also used an application called jetBrains dotpeek so I can read the dll file on the client machine and it seems to me the everything look ok I will check Fusion Logging and I'll let you know it I got any results

Comment: @O.A.K Is the `Copy Local`property from the reference set to `True` ?